# How to wrap string in span before and after all newlines in PHP?

Tags: php, string, function

Upon searching I found PHP function that do inserts 
 before all newlines in a string which is

```
nl2br();
```

**example:**

```
<?php
   echo nl2br("This is an example\r\n where line breaks\r\n added", false);
?>
```

Above code Output :

```
This is an example<br\>
where line breaks<br\> 
added
```

What I wanted to have output instead of <br/> I will wrap the string with the  tags before and after all newlines

**example output from code above wrap string with span**

```
<span>This is an example</span>
<span>where line breaks</span> 
<span>added</span>
```

Is there PHP function exist to this? or a custom PHP function

Comment: You could try something with [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $str = "This is an example\r\n where line breaks\r\n added";
    $str = explode("\r\n",$str);
    foreach($str as $key => $value) {
       echo "<span>".$value."</span>";
}
```

Comment: You can also replace `foreach` with `echo '<span>' . implode('</span><span>', $str) . '</span>';`

Answer (score 1):

You could do an "explode" on "\r\n" and loop over each value with a concatenated span.

Something like

```
$values = explode("\r\n", "one\r\ntwo\r\nthree\r\nfour")
$newvalues = ""

foreach($values as $value){
    $newvalues = $newvalues . "<span>" . $value . "</span>"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `file()`.  It will return the entire file as an array, each being a new line.  Iterate through there and add your span's.  Not the best way, but if you have a lot of files to do this for, it's just as easy as any other solution.  Otherwise, just explode on your delimiter.

Comment: +1 for the use of `file()`.  Of the 20 examples at least you offer something new.

Answer (score 0):

```
function splitToSpans($string) {
    $lines = explode('\r\n', $string);
    $finalString = '';
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        $finalString .= '<span>' . $line . '</span>';
    }
    return $finalString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$strout = '';
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $input);
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $strout .= "<span>$line</span>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

```
<?php
$string = "Line 1
Line 2
Line 3";
$string = preg_replace('/^(.*)$/m', '<span>$1</span>', $string);
echo $string;
```

Option 2:

```
<?php
$string = "Line 1\r\nLine 2\r\nLine 3";
$string = array_map(function($value) {
    return "<span>$value</span>";
}, explode("\r\n", $string));
echo implode("\r\n", $string);
```

Comment: I like the array_map implementation, but doing an explode and implode seems like overkill.

Answer (score 0):

This function splits the string based on either a CRLF or LF only and then wraps it into a `<span>` tag, applying proper escaping (important):

```
function nl2span($str)
{
    $r = '';
    foreach (preg_split("/\r?\n/", $str) as $line) {
        $r .= '<span>' . htmlspecialchars($line). '</span>';
    }
    return $r;
}
```

If your line endings are *always* CRLF you can replace the `preg_split()` with a more conventional `explode("\r\n", ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "This is an example\r\n where line breaks\r\n added";
var_dump($string); 
// string(46) "This is an example
// where line breaks
// added"
array_map(function($s){echo sprintf('<span>%s</span>', trim($s));}, explode("\r\n", $string));
// <span>This is an example</span>
// <span>where line breaks</span>
// <span>added</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is useful:

```
function nl2span( $str) {
    return '<span>' . implode( '</span><span>', explode( "\r\n", $str ) ) . '</span>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read through the answers, and noone had mentioned this solution...

```
$string = "This is an example\r\n where line breaks\r\n added";
echo '<span>' . str_replace('\r\n', '</span><span>', $string) . '</span>';
```