# How to add every single charater end and begining

Tags: php

I have : TEXTRANDOM

I want to replace like:

```
1T_1E_1X_1T_etc...
```

Solved:

```
<?php
$str = "TEXTRANDOM";
$len = strlen($str);
for($i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i) 
echo "1".$str[$i]."_";
?>
```

Comment: `<font>` is obsolete. Why do you want to use it?

Comment: i just want use that

Comment: Ok, but there might be a much better option. Sure you could use `array_map('yourfn', explode('', $yourText)`, but maybe there is an option to do what you want without using old HTML tags. [Check this question out.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148830/how-to-wrap-string-in-span-before-and-after-all-newlines-in-php)

Comment: i want to add every single character.
ABC
with
1A_1B_1C_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`preg_split('//u', $yourText, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) and [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) like this:

```
$yourText = 'TEXTRANDOM';
// execute a function for every letter in your string
$arrayOfTags = array_map(function (string $letter): string {
    return '1'.$letter.'_'; // concat every letter with number and _
}, preg_split('//u', $yourText, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
echo implode('', $arrayOfTags); // make the array into a string back again
```

`str_split` will split the string into bytes instead of letters. To split the string into array of letters you can use `preg_split('//u', $yourText, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)`.
You can also do it with just a loop:

```
$arrayOfletters = preg_split('//u', $yourText, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
foreach ($arrayOfletters as $letter) {
    echo '1'.$letter.'_';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Solved:

```
<?php
$str = "TEXTRANDOM";
$len = strlen($str);
for($i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i) 
echo "1".$str[$i]."_";
?>
```